# Porting Issue - Internet Explorer to Everything Else

Tags: javascript

I have some code which was developed on a Windows 7 computer and runs any Windows 7 compeer without any hiccups. I tried running it on my Mac and the program just stays on the loading page.

The program displays the bing maps view and loads a few things in order to get the location of a particular satellite. Now all the maths and stuff works but I think the problem lies here:

```
function getOrbitalElements()
{
TLE_Line1="";
TLE_Line2="";
pgTXT = "";
xmlhttp = null;
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
if (xmlhttp!=null)
{
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

}
```

So is there any way that this can be changed to run on any browser? Thanks 
P.S. If you need to see the entire code I'll add it

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries (like jQuery)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no ActiveX objects on Mac. The following line won't work:

```
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

You could use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest):

```
var xmlhttp = null;  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...  
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older  
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  

if (xmlhttp != null) {
    ...
}
```

But if you are seeking best cross browser support I would recommend you using a javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to perform your AJAX requests.

Comment: It works well on Safari - but it doesn't work on Google Chrome or Firefox - what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

with

```
xmlhttp = window.ActiveXObject?new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**EDIT**

As others have said, you might find benefit in using something like jQuery (which is very good) but you may not need to take the effort to adjust your existing code just yet.  If you have written good (standards) javascript, you will find the browser cross-compatibility issues should be minimal.

In the future, be sure to test in other browsers early and often to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to port a particular web app from a Browser specific version to a browser agnostic one is to use a javascript framework like jQuery.  It's designed to smooth out the rough edges that come up between different browsers into a friendly + unified API.  For example the above code could be done across multiple browsers with a jQuery ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function ()  {
    // Called when the query completes
    statechange();
  }});
```